# Java Math.signum doesn't evaluate workout error

Tags: java, type-conversion

I want to ask a question about `Math.signum()` in Java.

I wrote the following code as part of the Java Dummies series tutorial:

```
public class MathClass {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int a = 27;
        int b = -32;
        a = Math.abs(a) * Math.signum(b); // a is now -27
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

I thought that given that `Math.signum(b)` returns a float of value `-1.0F`, it would mean that `a` would also be converted to a float, and a is assigned the value of `-27`. However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from float to int
    a = Math.abs(a) * Math.signum(b); // a is now -27
```

I'm confused by the error.

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 1):

`Math.signum(b)` returns a float, so int * float will be of float type, which you are trying to store into an int. If you want to use an int for the result, you need to convert the float to an int.

```
a = Math.abs(a) * (int) Math.signum(b);
```

Otherwise, store the result in a float/double variable

```
float x = Math.abs(a) * Math.signum(b);
```

Note that once a variable is declared, you cannot change its type!

Comment: It appears the Dummies' Book is therefore incorrect, as I suspected! Many thanks!

Comment: It would be better to use the correct `signum` method instead, i.e. the one that takes an `int` parameter and returns an `int` value.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you're calling the wrong `signum()` method.

Use the [`Integer.signum(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum-int-) method instead of the [`Math.signum(float f)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum-float-) method.

Oh, and if you print `a` instead of `test`, the code will actually compile and run.

```
int a = 27;
int b = -32;
a = Math.abs(a) * Integer.signum(b);
System.out.println(a); // prints: -27
```

Comment: Apologies! I updated the answer to reflect the correct code - that was a typo from a previous build! Many thanks!